# import with jest error: Unexpected token import

Tags: import, jestjs

I've seen similar questions but still can't find a viable solution.

I'm trying to integrate Jest into a working project, which uses import/export default in hundreds of places. The following test does work for Jest using require:

```
const bar = require('../../flows/foo');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(bar.foobar(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

when export is:

```
module.exports = { 
 foobar: foobar,
  fizz: fizz
}
```

The functions I'll want to be testing however are exported using:

```
export default {
  foobar: foobar,
  fizz: fizz
};
```

So when I try to update my test to import:

```
import foobar from '../../flows/foo';
```

With export:

```
export default {foobar: foobar};
```

I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

#### All it takes:

```js
// run this command (or npm equivalent)
yarn add @babel/core @babel/preset-env

// add babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

Jest automatically picks it up, no other configuration required.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set up a `.babelrc` file in your project, so transpiling is not happening. You need to transpile the ES6+ syntax (`import`, `export`, etc) into browser readable ES5.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and solved it this way thanks to [this GitHub issue post](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2081#issuecomment-306706600):

If you're using babel to transpile your code then remember to use the `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` plugin.

To use it, you'll need to:

1. Install the plugin for BabelJS by entering this command in the CLI:

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`

2. Add the plugin to your list of plugins in your babel config

```
plugins: [
  "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
]
```