# Jest fails to import with Typescript (SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

When I run Jest tests with Typescript, I get the following error on an external TS file import called in a `node_modules` library:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I'm sure I'm missing a configuration but what is it? Thanks for your help.

Here is my configuration:

- `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "strict": true,
  "module": "node",
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": ["src", "tests"]
}
```

- `jest.config.js`

```js
    module.exports = {
      roots: ['<rootDir>'],
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      testRegex: 'tests/.*\\.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$',
      transform: {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
      },
      moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
      moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/jest.setup.ts'],
      collectCoverage: true,
      collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js{,x},ts{,x}}', '!src/index.tsx'],
    }
```

- `webpack.config.js`

```js
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
    const path = require('path')
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    
    module.exports = {
      entry: './src/index.tsx',
      mode: 'development',
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: { presets: ['@babel/env'] },
          },
          {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          },
        ],
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        alias: { 'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom' },
      },
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'app.js',
      },
      devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/dist/',
        hotOnly: true,
      },
      plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63870080/ts-node-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module/63962457?noredirect=1) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553020/import-with-jest-error-unexpected-token-import/63962423#63962423). I was able to fix this issue by adding transform-es2015-modules-commonjs. See this post for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63962423/2684661

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, please check if all paths in your imports are correct
in my case i had `import NavbarCollapse from "react-bootstrap/esm/NavbarCollapse";`
instead of `import NavbarCollapse from "react-bootstrap/NavbarCollapse";`

Comment: The issue is happening inside a library in `node_modules`, there is no wrong import with it. And my app runs fine, it's just the test that doesn't work.

Comment: +1 this, this is an issue with VSCode sometimes importing from wrong node_modules dir with it's auto import feature. Didn't notice the 'esm' bit for hours!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the

```
  "module": "node",
```

line in your tsconfig.json. Remove that. You have the correct module specification (commonjs) inside your compilerOptions section.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I removed the line but I still have the issue when running the test. I guess that the current config is fine since I can run the app without any issue, but there must be something specific to Jest that is missing...

Comment: Does your project have .js files as well as .ts? If so, you could try:
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',

Comment: I don't. I still tried it just in case but still doesn't work. The issue seems to happen only for a `.ts` file imported by a library in `node_modules`. Even if I add it as an exception in `transformIgnorePatterns` (even the opposite with `!`), it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the line that is causing the syntax error? Is it in a test file, or in a file that is being tested? Are there other import statements in the file that work?

Comment: In a source file, I'm using the [Web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) library. The line failing is `node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/src/secp256k1.ts:1` containing:
`import { privateKeyVerify } from "secp256k1";`

Comment: I'm pretty convinced it's all about the transformation with `ts-test`